# C# How to check the solution configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For my project I don't use the standard *Debug* and *Release* solution configurations, instead I have custom configurations e.g. ReleaseConfig1.

In C# is there anyway I can check what release configuration the project was built against.

I tried the below but it always goes to the else:

```
#if ReleaseConfig1
//blah
#else
//blah blah
#endif
```

My solution configuration looks something like this:

```
ReleaseConfig1:
Project 1: Release
Project 2: ReleaseSpecialXXX
Project 3: Debug

ReleaseConfig2:
Project 1: ReleaseSpecialZZZ
Project 2: Release
Project 3: Debug
```

Comment: Define "Does not work" - What exactly are you putting inside the preprocessor conditional statements?

Comment: Does this cover it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/507704/108847

Comment: @Colin: It always returns false since the solution configuration doesn't seem to get defined as a constant 
@Fishcake: Actually I think it might. Unless someone can state otherwise I guess the answer is "no, not directly possible".

Comment: Hi @row1, did you ever find a proper solution? I think I work the same like you do; I always used the Solution Configuration to change from Test, Production and Acceptance database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projects are really the active part of MSBuild. Solutions are kind of a VS only thing and aren't all that involved in building, other than determining build order. Anything that actually affects the assembly output is done in the project.

Using the standard DEBUG constant is really the way to go. The autogenerated projects are set-up to do this when they are created, so using those configurations/convention is a really good way to go and avoids tedious custom configuration.

Comment: What Visual Studio calls a solution it originally called a workspace; see [File Types Created for Visual C++ Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278994%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The dsw file type is for workspaces that became solutions in later versions of VS; I think beginning with .Net versions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define compile time constants for each configuration.  You can check against those.

I believe the standard Debug config has DEBUG set to true etc.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like you would need to do that for each project configuration and not solution configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly same question as [How do I check the active solution configuration Visual Studio built with at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496/how-do-i-check-the-active-solution-configuration-visual-studio-built-with-at-runt)

Comment: I think it is similar but different. My current understanding regarding that question's answer is that for #if to work I would be required to define conditional compilation symbols for each project and for each project configuration.
I am hoping that I can determine the solution configuration and not the project configuration.

Comment: Did Fishcake's comment on your original question resolve your query?